# How to get a list beside this box element I have drawn?

Tags: html, css

I have been browsing forums and trying to apply the information I read about relative position and floats and so on but so far have had no luck. I just started writing HTML and CSS yesterday.

The bulk of the site is contained in a box defined more or less like this:

```
body {
margin: 150px ; 
text-align: left;
}
.box {
    color: black ;
    width: 390px ;
    border: 1px solid black ;
    padding: 2em ;
}
```

```
<body>
<div class="box">
CONTENT
</div>
```

And I have a list

```
<div>
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
</div>
```

Which I want to show up along the right side of this box that I have drawn. What is the easiest way for me to position it there?

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0Jxi.jpg) is a screenshot of the whole thing I am playing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) very useful when positioning elements. To solve your particular problem try this:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="box">
      CONTENT
    </div> 
    <div>
      <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.box-container{
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: That worked! I've encountered a new problem though! It seems that the list and the main content box TOGETHER are centred in the page. However, I would like to keep the contents box the same size and position as it is in my screenshot and simply tack the list on beside it. Is there an easy fix for this or does the whole process need to be rethought now?

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/4Vp3WR9) is what I'm looking at now. (Thank you for such a speedy reply by the way!! I will definitely be looking through this flexbox thing) :)

Comment: No problem. Try adding `flex: 1` to `.box` class

Comment: That made the contents box more narrow rather than wider 

Comment: Remove `width: 100%` from `.menu` and `flex: 1` from `.box` - then play with the width of the `.box` class until you get your desired result

Comment: Thank you so much! And thank you also for all your patience!! :)

Comment: No problem :) Can you please mark it as the answer?

Comment: Did it go through properly? And do you have a website or anything like that that I can see some of your work etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Add those styles to your body tag.

```
body {
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-right: 70px;
  text-align: left;
}
```